# How to send commands from a file to VIM?

Tags: command-line, vim

This is the content of `cmd.txt`:

```
:w 2.txt
:q
```

In command line, I do

```
D:\>vim 1.txt<cmd.txt
```

I expect cmd.txt as input stream (rather than my keyboard) and vim will save 1.txt as 2.txt and then quit.

It however doesn't work. Vim says input is not from a terminal and freeze.

I want to send commands from external file. How to do this?

**Update:**

What I want to do is to substitute a lot of patterns. I have a file which talks about NBA history, where the name of a team is refered to the city and I want to change it to the "last name".

I have somehow generated the substitution commands (30 rules/rows):

```
:%s/\v<Boston>/Celtics/g
:%s/\v<Brooklyn>/Nets/g
:%s/\v<New York>/Knicks/g
:%s/\v<Philadelphia>/76ers/g
:%s/\v<Toronto>/Raptors/g
:%s/\v<Golden St>/Warriors/g
:%s/\v<LA Clippers>/Clippers/g
:%s/\v<LA Lakers>/Lakers/g
:%s/\v<Phoenix>/Suns/g
:%s/\v<Sacramento>/Kings/g
:%s/\v<Chicago>/Bulls/g
:%s/\v<Cleveland>/Cavaliers/g
:%s/\v<Detroit>/Pistons/g
:%s/\v<Indiana>/Pacers/g
:%s/\v<Milwaukee>/Bucks/g
.....
```

I want to input the file to vim to execute these commands. I don't want to type thses commands manually.

I may generate the rules in another way and input it to other program, or even write a simple program to do the substitution. But I will appreciate if it can be done in Vim, Powershell, or Total Commanders I'm learning recently.

Comment: Vim is an interactive editor, so what you're trying to do won't work, it just doesn't expect commands this way. It sounds a lot like you're using the wrong tool to get something done. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the `-s` command-line option:

```
vim -s cmd.txt 1.txt
```

However, Teun Vink's comment is still valid.  What are you actually trying to do?  This sounds like the classic [X->Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Well, my answer shows you how to do it if you really want to use Vim, but it would probably be better to learn to use `sed` for this kind of work.

Comment: I find a new command. If the file content is `i123<esc>:w` and I run it by `:source!`, `123<esc>:w` is verbatimly inserted. It indicates `<esc>` is not translated to <kbd>esc</kbd> key. What is the correct way to write <kbd>esc</kbd> key?

Comment: You're going to have to put a raw escape character directly in the file. You can do that with Vim by pressing `control-v` then pressing the `escape` key while in insert mode.

Comment: Thanks, and here I find the documentation `:help i_CTRL-V`.

Comment: Do you think we can use this to "support" +clientserver for macVim on terminal ?
I'm opeing my macVim on terminal, then executing `:termianl` and inside that terminal I want an alias to remap vim. So that you dont get vim inside vim, instead to write into the "keyInput buffer" a tabe ..... In linux I can easelly remap ti to : `alias vim=vim --remote-tab`

Answer (score 3):

I know this post is an old one, but what @Gqqnbig is asking for is possible.

Simply save the list of command you want to execute frequently to a file. Ideally give it a .vim extension e.g. nbaEdits.vim

In the data file you want to execute the commands against simply issue this command from the VIM command line (I've only tried this via Windows):

```
:source c:\myVimCommands\nbaEdits.vim
```

**The above assumes your command file is located in a folder at c:\myVimCommands